# Open .cbr files

Tags: files

Is it possible to open a [CBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_archive) file with Emacs?

I am not asking for a package similar to [MComix](http://sourceforge.net/p/mcomix/wiki/), just a quick way to read the content of a .cbr file.

Comment: According to the link you cited:  *Comic book archive files are not a distinct file format; only the file name extension differs from a standard file of the given archive type.*  The standard formats include: .cb7 (i.e., 7z); cba (i.e., ACE); .cbr (i.e., RAR); .cbt (i.e., TAR); and .cbz (i.e., ZIP).  Emacs contains `archive-mode`, which can open `*.rar` files if you have that utility installed.  So, you need that utility *plus* you need to add `cbr` to the `auto-mode-alist` for `archive-mode` -- i.e., `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.\\(cbr\\)\\'" . archive-mode))`

Comment: The full version of `RAR` is not free; however, it does have a free trial.  Unfortunately, `archive-mode` is out-of-date and needs a tweak or two to properly handle the current version of `RAR` -- that is a different question than the one you are asking.  I have already configured a custom version of `archive-mode` to take advantage of the *current* full version of `RAR` -- so if you decide to go that route, then post a new question . . . If you have an older version of `RAR` or can find an older version, then you will not need to modify `archive-mode`.

Comment: This is the ```RAR``` I have installed: ```rar: Installed: 2:5.2.0-dmo1```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing `unrar-free` (I am on Debian sid) and adding `.cbr` to `archive-mode` as suggested by lawlist [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7724/open-cbr-files#comment11562_7724), did the trick.

Comment: unrar-free will be ditched in upcoming releases of emacs, you will need to have unarchiver installed instead, source: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=25979c8e35e0f4fdb21b873b6976177df0b02e02